# ruby on rails scope joins table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scope

I want to joins 2 tables users and countries. I have tried this without success:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to    :country

  scope :ind, joins(:countries).where("countries.name like %india%")
end
```

When I call this method, I got this error:

```
1.9.3-p484 :016 > user_ind = User.ind
NoMethodError: undefined method `ind' for #<Class:0xaa5ed94>
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):16
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
scope :ind, -> { joins(:country).where("countries.name like %india%") }
```

The name in the `joins` should be the name of the *association*, not the table from the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations):

> Active Record lets you use the names of the associations defined on
>   the model as a shortcut for specifying JOIN clause for those
>   associations when using the joins method.

Scope syntax without callable object is `deprecated`:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Using #scope without passing a callable object is
>   deprecated. For example `scope :red, where(color: 'red')` should be
>   changed to `scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }`. There are
>   numerous gotchas in the former usage and it makes the implementation
>   more complicated and buggy. (If you prefer, you can just define a
>   class method named `self.red`.).